# Generic component with events

Tags: angular

I'm fairly new at angular and I am interested in creating a generic confirmation popup component that can be used in multiple scenarios. For example for both deleting or saving an entry the user must confirm the action, so a simple popup will be displayed (some text, a cancel and ok button). According to the action performed by the user, I want that ok button to delete or save an item. Can this be achieved and how? (to send the corresponding method that needs to be done to that generic component).

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible. Just provide an async API for your popup. In order to view it, the builder pattern might be useful. Make sure to return Promise/Observable, so that in the component opening the dialog, you can react based on the result.

Some code that I had to simplify for this answer. It uses material dialog to create a generic confirm dialog with cancel, title, msg and confirm. Subscribe to `show` in order to get the result. You'll have to play around with this code, it wasn't tested in this simpler form. But it should give you an idea on how to get your generic dialog done.

**call it with (e.g. from your component):**

```
 new ConfirmDialogPresenter(this.mdDialog);
```

confirm-dialog-instance.ts

```
export class ConfirmDialogPresenter {

  private _title = '';
  private _message = '';
  private _confirmLabel = '';
  private _cancelLabel = '';


  constructor(private mdDialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  title(title: string): ConfirmDialogPresenter {
    this._title = title;
    return this;
  }

  message(message: string): ConfirmDialogPresenter {
    this._message = message;
    return this;

  }

  confirmLabel(confirmLabel: string): ConfirmDialogPresenter {
    this._confirmLabel = confirmLabel;
    return this;

  }

  cancelLabel(cancelLabel: string): ConfirmDialogPresenter {
    this._cancelLabel = cancelLabel;
    return this;

  }

  show(): Observable<boolean | undefined> {
    const dialogRef = this.mdDialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.title = this._title;
    dialogRef.componentInstance.message = this._message;
    dialogRef.componentInstance.confirmLabel = this._confirmLabel;
    dialogRef.componentInstance.cancelLabel = this._cancelLabel;
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }
}
```

confirm-dialog.component.html

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>
    {{title}}
</h1>
<mat-dialog-content>
    {{message}}
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="confirm()">{{confirmLabel}}</button>
    <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="secondary" (click)="close()">{{cancelLabel}}</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

confirm-dialog.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirm-dialog',
  templateUrl: './confirm-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirm-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class ConfirmDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  title: string;
  message: string;
  confirmLabel: string = "Okay!";
  cancelLabel: string = "Cancel";

  constructor(public readonly dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmDialogComponent>) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close(false);
  }

  confirm() {
    this.dialogRef.close(true);
  }

}
```